# Using WPF DataGridHyperLinkColumn Items to open Windows Explorer and open files

Tags: wpf, datagrid, hyperlink, uri

I want to achieve the following:

Create a WPF DataGrid that have 2 columns:

The first will have items showing paths to directories, in a hyperlink style. Clicking on a hyperlink will open Windows Explorer in the path specified by the item.

The second will have items showing paths to files, in a hyperlink style. Clicking on a hyperlink will launch the file, with the default application defined by Windows.

I don't know if it's the right choice, but I added DataGridHyperlinkColumn's to my DataGrid. One problem was to add Uri items that do not refer to an internet locations. Another problem was to handle the clicks in a way that does not open a web browser.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This works universally:

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Link}">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

```
private void DG_Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
    Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

If the URI points a website it will be opened with the default web-browser, if it is a folder it will be opened in explorer, if it is a file it will be opened with the default application associated with it.

---

To use this for autogenerated columns your property needs to be of type `Uri` so a `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` is generated. You then can hook up the event by placing the style in the `DataGrid.Resources`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! By the way, how is this done when the columns are autogenerated (from a datatable in my case)?

Comment: I added some info regarding that to my answer, but i do not know if that works for `DataTables` as i never used them (you need to have a `Uri`-Property).

Comment: Is it possible to specify a link other than the one binded?

Comment: @flux: Sure, you will still have a call to `Process.Start` or something similar somewhere in your code, what you pass in is entirely up to you.

Comment: I mean can you put a binding through a converter in order to display a short hyperlink, but then use the full path when clicked on?

Comment: @flux: Probably, that's not what this question is about though, so please ask a separate one if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @H.B. I was wondering if you would have time to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59481361/1232087) that is using your above suggestion.