# datagrid and href link wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a column in my datagrid that contains only URL, I would like to make all of them clickable, what do have I have to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using WPF DataGridHyperLinkColumn Items to open Windows Explorer and open files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764951/using-wpf-datagridhyperlinkcolumn-items-to-open-windows-explorer-and-open-files)

Answer (score 0):

Give mouse click event to your datagrid and wright code behind.

```
 <WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Binding}"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseClick" >
```

Code Behind

```
private void OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
//Do something

}
```