# setting a specific data grid cell as hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i am using a WPF native data grid with 2 text columns ,some values in my table are paths to local files.  I am looking for a way to make specific cells (according to their values) appear as hyperlink , clicking on those cells will open their content in the default application associated to their file type.

i found this [Using WPF DataGridHyperLinkColumn Items to open Windows Explorer and open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764951/using-wpf-datagridhyperlinkcolumn-items-to-open-windows-explorer-and-open-files) in order to complete the 2nd task but i cant find a way to change only specific cells without changing the entire column type.
thanks,

Comment: You could either do this using DataGridTemplateColumn, or by assigning the ItemTemplateSelector of your DataGrid.  It depends on your needs.  Aside from a hyperlink, what other possible data needs to be shown in that column?

Comment: @Moozhe my data grid displays mainly ints and floats but some entries have string values that usually point to a file.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i am not Core-WPF developer, but i can suggest you something
add Click event, and on the click event , check for selected cell's ref, 
if it matches with your then make call to that hyperlink, else do nothing.

for example, you dgv is like

```
Name    Age
Err     20
Ron     23
Hkr     99
Nub     00
```

and you want user should go to Respective persone profile page as they click on name, so u should
*Inside Click Event*

`switch(dgv.SelectedCell.index){`
`case 0: //go to Err's page;`
`case 1: //go to Ron's page`
`case default: //go to hell :-p;`
`}`