# WPF - DataGridHyperlinkColumn not opening local HTML file

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

**Environment**: `VS2019 - ver 16.4.2`, `Windows 10 - Pro ver 1903`, `WPF Core 3.1`

Why the following code is not opening the file from the link in `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` in my `WPF` app. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5765425/1232087) it should open the file - unless I'm missing something here.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_DataGrid_EFCore.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_DataGrid_EFCore"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,43,0,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}">
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="dgTest_HyperLink_Click"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="355,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.Xaml.cs**

```
private void dgTest_HyperLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
    Console.WriteLine(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri); //correctly shows the path as file:///C:/Users/MyUserName/AppData/Local/Temp/TestLocalFile.htm
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

**Remark**

1. The file is there and I can manually open it by pasting the following link directly to the Windows Explorer: `file:///C:/Users/MyUserName/AppData/Local/Temp/TestLocalFile.htm`. It opens in my default browser `Google Chrome`.
2. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5765425/1232087) the file should open.

**Error**

> > System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
> >       HResult=0x80004005
> >       Message=The system cannot find the file specified.
> >       Source=System.Diagnostics.Process ....
> >     .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the code, which is launching link per follows

```cs
private void dgTest_HyperLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
    Console.WriteLine(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri); //correctly shows the path as file:///C:/Users/MyUserName/AppData/Local/Temp/TestLocalFile.htm

    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri,
        UseShellExecute = true
    };
    Process.Start(psi);
}
```

[`UseShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8) does the magic here, in .NET Core it's set to `false` by default and

> When `UseShellExecute` is false, the `FileName` property can be either a
>   fully qualified path to the executable, or a simple executable name
>   that the system will attempt to find within folders specified by the
>   PATH environment variable.

In your case file name isn't executable, so for make it working you have to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`, this is correct for .NET Core apps.

The attached answer is 8 years old and using the classic .NET, where this property is `true` by default. You may also refer to this GitHub [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10361) for details