# Implementing clickable hyperlinks into a datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink

I am currently working on a project where I am required to read information from an Excel file and display results based on certain search parameters and display the entirety of the row where the searched parameter's value is equal to the parameter's value in the row in the Excel file. I then display the information from each matching row in a DataGrid on a separate Window. One of the pieces of information that is being displayed in the DataGrid is a link that points to a location on a company server where information regarding the searched items can be found. I would like to know how to be able to make this link clickable and, once clicked take the user to that files directory location in the server. Perhaps I should note that the DataGrid is contained in a normal window (not a navigational window, for instance) and the file location on the server acts as a hyperlink on the Excel document itself, so from the Excel document I can click the link and it will take me to the appropriate server location. I've just been frustrated trying to get the same behavior once the link is on the DataGrid in the Window in my app that displays the search result. I've tried several solutions, such as attempting to make the column holding the link a DataGridHyperlinkColumn and trying to set up an event and event handler for the Hyperlink.Click event but with no luck and I can't seem to find a solution that works anywhere. Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5765425/4860688

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should define DataGridTemplateColumn in your XAML. Then you can assign any control to CellTemplate or CellEditingTemplate

In the following example I use my UserControl for editing and standard TextBox for showing. The UserControl may contain code for click handling or whatever

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Effect}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource TimeCol}">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbEffect" Text="{Binding Effect, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TextToTimeConverter}}" Background="Transparent"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <local:TimeTextBox x:Name="tmtEffect" TimeText="{Binding Effect, Converter={StaticResource TextToTimeConverter }, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```